# WebFarm URL Rewrite

Tags: load-balancing, web-farm

I have configured 3 server, one is controller and other two servers with ASP.NET application running on port 81. Application are accessible from the two servers directly using port 81.

Now, I want these applications to be accessible from controller (for load balancing) using port 81.

How to configure URL Rewrite rule for same.

From the browsers(client machine), I am accessing all my servers using IP addresses.

When the applications use port 80, the URL Rewrite rule created for Web Farm works correctly and load balancing is done as expected.

Thanks!!!